# How to applescript the 'grab' application

Tags: applescript, screen-capture

I am trying to write an apple script to use the "Grab" application in the Utilities folder to capture and print an application's window.

I can get to the part where I tell Grab to start window capture mode, but I can't seem to script clicking of another applications window to cause the correct window to be captured.

I have tried the "click at {x,y}" without success.  All of the screen capture scripts I have found thus far do entire screen only with a command line tool.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `screencapture -l` to target a specific window.

```
-l<windowid> capture this windowsid
```

You can find the IDs with [AppleScript or Quartz Debug](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56561/how-do-i-find-the-windowid-to-pass-to-screencapture-l/56566#56566).

Comment: oh, very cool! Had not thought of that...